# Python - Função que copia o conteudo de uma lista para outra lista

Tags: python, funções, lista

Preciso de uma função (copia_lista, abaixo transcrita) que recebe duas listas, dest e orig, e copia o conteudo de orig para dest, vide exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> a = [8, 9]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> copia_lista(a, b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

O código que implementei abaixo não funciona. Alguém saberia me explicar o por que?

```
def copia_lista(dest, orig):
    ''' (list, list) -> None'''

    dest = orig.copy()
```

Answer (score 6):

Não vejo isso como algo útil para produção, mas supondo que é apenas um exercício, vamos lá.

```
def copia_lista(dest, orig):
    ''' (list, list) -> None'''
    dest = orig.copy()
```

Quando você faz isso você basicamente está criando um objeto `dest` novo, no escopo local da função, que neste escopo, sobrescreverá o objeto `dest` recebido como parâmetro. Quando a função termina de executar, o escopo local é finalizado e o objeto `dest` que você criou é perdido, mantendo inalterado o `dest` original.

Como lista é um tipo mutável, basta você apenas alterar o objeto sem fazer uma nova atribuição.

```
def copia_lista(dest, orig):
    ''' (list, list) -> None'''
    dest.clear()  # Remove os elementos de dest
    for item in orig:
        dest.append(item)
```

Desta forma,

```
>>> a = [8, 9]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> copia_lista(a, b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Uma forma mais simples de executar a mesma lógica seria:

```
def copia_lista(dest, orig):
    ''' (list, list) -> None'''
    dest[:] = orig
```

Produzindo o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575337/10746978), no momento que você faz:

`dest =orig.copy()`

O que o interpretador faz é pegar o nome (ou "etiqueta") `dest`, do escopo interno, e colocar ela no objeto retornado pelo método `orig.copy()`. O nome `a` da chamada da função continua atrelado ao mesmo objeto original.

Uma forma de fazer isso seria modificar sua função para ter um retorno, e esse retorno ser atribuído a variável desejada:

```
def copia(orig):
    return orig.copy()
a=copia(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi a utilidade do código, mas de modo direto ficaria assim:

```
import copy


def copia_lista(lista):
    '''Retorna a cópia de uma lista. '''
    return copy.copy(lista)

lista_A = [1, 2, 3]

copia = copia_lista(lista_A)    

lista_A.append(9)

print(copia) # [1, 2, 3]
print(lista_A) # [1, 2, 3, 9]
```

Dessa forna você possui duas listas alocadas em partes diferentes na memória podendo manipular uma e mantendo a original intacta. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Essa não é exatamente a solução apresentada anteriormente [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402421/5878)?

Answer (score 1):

Não tem um jeito (apropriado) pra modificar objetos em Python usando uma função. Tu não pode (ou não deveria) alterar o valor de **b** dentro da função **copia_lista**.

A forma apropriada é atribuir o retorno de uma função à variável:

```
def copia_lista(orig):
  return orig.copy()

a = [8, 9]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = copia_lista(b)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Dito isto, se por "copiar" tu quis dizer que o que tu queria era acrescentar o conteúdo de **b** em **a**, então o método é outro:

```
def copia_lista(dest, orig):
  return dest + orig

a = [8, 9]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = copia_lista(a, b)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Resultado:

```
[8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

E para quem não entendeu a utilidade deste código, dentro da função **copia_lista** a gente pode introduzir outros processamentos que simplesmente fazendo `a = b.copy()` não faz.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um outro jeito menos eficiente, porém faz a mesma coisa e quantos mais métodos melhor, já q pode ser aplicado em outras situações.

```
def Copiar(B):
    for i in B:
        A.append(i)


A=[1,2,3,4]
B=[5,6,7,8]

Copiar(B)

print(A)
print(B)
```

Aí está a atribuição sem retorno era oq vc estava tentando fazer.

Comment: O único detalhe é que ela mantém os valores iniciais da lista, enquanto seria esperado, dada a pergunta, que eles fossem removidos.

Comment: Isso.. mas eu acho q era isso q ele estava tentando fazer, já q ele passou duas listas e ficou insatisfeito pelo retorno Iguais... a lógica q eu ele tipo penso foi... com a def copia(a,b) tipo copiá b é junta com a n sei.. só presumo, independente disso agora ele contém mais conhecimento adquirido :)